# make a living out of / off (of) / from / by & live off (of) / on

Tags: prepositions, difference

Are all these phrases interchangeable as I think?

Examples:

1. I **make a living out** of my small business.
2. I **make a living off** **of** my small business.

   a. I **make a living off** my small business.
3. I **make a living from** my small business.
4. I **make a living by** my small business.
5. I **live off** **of** my small business.

   a. I **live off** my small business.
6. I **live on** my small business.

   or maybe,

   a. I **live on** my small business **income**.

Answer (score 1):

There are minor differences and some of them do not sound as fluent as others. Here is my evaluation.

> 1 is alright
>
> 2 sounds less fluent but still works.
>
> 2a same as 2
>
> 3 is alright
>
> 4 does not sound right.
>
> 5 is alright
>
> 5a is alright (5 is better though)
>
> 6 is rather idiomatic but works.
>
> 6a should be "I live on my small business's income"

Comment: Thank you. Could you please tell me why we need to use the apostrophe in 6a.?

Comment: @Luke as it is possessive.

Comment: Another way to put it is 'the income of my small business'

Comment: Yes, but "small business" is a thing. Could you please tell me the rule for using apostrophes with things? Is it also possible to write it as I did originally, as a compound noun ("small business income")? Thanks.

Comment: Oh I didn't interpret it that way. In that case you're right